# Each div get height of parent - jQuery approach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this structure:

```
<div class="container" style="height:(variable height)">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="height:(variable height)">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="height:(variable height)">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

So I need each `.box` gets the height of the parent `.container` which has different heights from the other and it varies.

I need ONLY jQuery approach, no CSS cause I don't want to use `absolute` position, `table-cell` or whatever to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: css height doesn't require special position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function overload of [`.height`](http://api.jquery.com/height)

```
$('.box').height(function(){
    return $(this).parent().height();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really must use jQuery:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    $(this).children().height($(this).height);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kgfLcasv/1/).

It's worth noting, though, that if `height` is set on the `.container` elements then you could simply assign:

```
.box {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kgfLcasv/2/).

No special `position`, or `display`, properties are required.

Incidentally, for a plain JavaScript sollution:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.container'), function (c) {
    [].forEach.call(c.children, function (b) {
        b.style.height = c.style.height;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kgfLcasv/3/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children).
- jQuery:

  - [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that `box` are floated elements. That's why it doesn't get the height that way

Comment: I think we may be talking about different issues, but CSS `height: 100%` definitely works (even for floated elements) so long as there's a defined height on the parent, see the [second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kgfLcasv/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('.container').each(function(i,e){
    $(this).find('.box').css('height',$(this).height())
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer inside itself ?

Comment: It will loop through all parent then find specif class & set the height of it's parent's height